# "Centrally" updated table in html

Tags: html, iframe

I am looking to add some html coding to my website that will pick up a simple 5 row table that is saved in a separate file.  I will then link to this table in number of pages, the idea being that I can update that separate file and the changes will feed into each of the pages it is used in.

I have built the table in file - test_table.html

And where I want the table to appear I tried using iframe:

```
<iframe src=/test_table.html width=300 height=300></iframe>
```

but this isn't displaying (offline, the website isn't published yet).  Is there a more appropriate method for doing this?

The purpose of the table is to show the top 5 new pages on the full site.  So I want to be able to simply update that file as the content is updated and this will appear in every page.

This has been hard to research online because any searching involving "table" and "html" just brings back results related to positioning and basic table functions.

Comment: is it actually finding test_table.html? can you check that the data is loading using developer tools? it might be an issue that you're not correctly linking to test_table.html.. in which case you wouldnt see anything.. also you should enclose your values in quotes `<iframe src="/test_table.html" width="300" height="300"></iframe>`

Comment: Hi, it's working now, <iframe src="latest_table.html" width="198" height="725"></iframe>
I also had to link it to a live website then switch it back to latest_table.html for it to update.  Silly work around but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think rather than using iframe, simple use a jQuery "get" method and dynamically load the file contents in the required location. For a start, please see the [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/WWL9Q/1/).

HTML:

```
<div id="dynamic">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get( "/test_table.html", function( data ) {
        $( "#dynamic" ).html( data );
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I'll try to get this working and report back.